# is there any way to get back the eth i send to my smart contract token?

Tags: solidity, ether, metamask

thhis the contract as you see the one eth is there
contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x19d71f00354ad302e89ca47e59b68917f9a871d7#code

Comment: Sorry, there's way too much code there. Please pinpoint the exact problem and explain what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, thks for posting question, It is a bit difficult exactly to understand what is exactly the problem, can you please add more context, so we can try to help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: guys i send eth and tokesn to smart contract to launch token from the smart contract so the open trading function dosent work so my eth got stuck on the contract. itried to liq manualy but i dont know how to use the function

Comment: so the proplem is there any way to get my stuck eth?